# How to auto-upgrade program (Inno Setup) on windows 7 without being admin?

Tags: windows-7, inno-setup, user-permissions

I use Inno setup to install python package (py2exe) on the program files folder. the first installation require admin privileged and it is ok.

The application has automatically upgrade option (it download the new setup exe ad run it in silence mode)

**The problem is that it fails because the user is not admin.**

My first though was to install the first installation in {pf} folder, but to install the updated pyc in the user folder. and somehow to tell the app to check for pyc in this folder.
But I don't know how to do it and if it can be done

Answer (score 1):

A normal application can not run an installer to update a system wide location without it asking for/requiring full admin access.

As it's best practice to prompt/warn the user before an upgrade the UAC prompt shouldn't be a problem.